# Swaping positions within an array vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, bubble-sort

I'm trying to code a program that has two sections depending on which of two buttons has been pressed.

The first section is the bit that is working, the user presses the first button labeled "unsort", this triggers a loop which displays an input box asking for a random number 8 times. These 8 numbers are stored in an array.

However it is the second section I'm struggling with; the second button is labeled sort and should output the numbers the user just entered using the first button is order, smallest to largest. I understand that a bubble sort must be used here and that a loop within a loop must also be used however it is the content of these loop that I don't understand. Since my original post I've edited the post to include some code in the loop I was previously stuck with, however it still isn't producing the desired output (all numbers in order) but is instead just outputting the numbers in a seemingly random order

The code is posted below with annotations:

```
Public Class BubbleSort1
    Dim Bubble(8) As Integer
    Dim UnsortedList As String
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim SortedList As String
    Dim temp As String


    Private Sub btnUnsort_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUnsort.Click
        n = 8 ' number off values on array
        For i = 1 To n ' when i is between 1 and size of array
            Bubble(i) = InputBox("Enter Number") ' User inputs a number
            UnsortedList = UnsortedList & " " & Bubble(i) & vbNewLine ' number is added to the unsorted list variable
        Next i
        lblUnsort.Text = UnsortedList ' outputs the array
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSort_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSort.Click

        For i = 1 To n - 1 ' When i is between 1 and the array size - 1 (8-1):
            For j = 1 To n - 1 ' Second loop - when j is between 1 and the array size - 1 (8-1):
                If Bubble(j) > Bubble(j + 1) Then ' if bubble value j is greater than value j - 1:
                    temp = Bubble(j)
                    Bubble(j) = Bubble(j + 1) ' These lines are supost to order the numbers but aren'r currently doing so
                    Bubble(j + 1) = temp
                    SortedList = SortedList & Bubble(j) & vbNewLine ' Adding the number in order to a variable 
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

        lblSort.Text = SortedList ' outputting the ordered numbers

    End Sub
End Class
```

As is pointed out in the code, the section of this code that orders the numbers is just putting them in a random order rather than actually ordering them.

Comment: this will give you the information you need for your school project. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort I'll help you after you put some code in there.

Comment: If you had a glass of red-coloured water (stick a label on it saying "Bubble(j)"), a glass of blue-coloured water (stick a label on it saying "Bubble(j + 1)"), and an empty glass labelled "temp", how would you swap the coloured water between the glasses?

Comment: "understand that a bubble sort must be used here " is this a requirement? There are already build-in sorting functions in .net

Comment: @the_lotus school project...the teacher wants to see if they understand the concept and if they are able to apply it

Comment: Yes, this is a requirement of the task

Comment: @Andrew Morton I put some code in there but the list isn't being ordered, just put into a random order

Comment: @JWilson You are building the `SortedList` string too early: if you create it after the sorting has been done I expect it will be in the correct order.

Comment: @Andrew Morton I've tried to move the line of code that builds the SortedList string out of the loop that does the sorting however a new problem has occurred. The line is question includes the variable j that is exclusive to the loop. This results in an error message that states "j is not declared, it may be inaccessible due to its protection level"

Comment: @JWilson It is good that you are trying this yourself without resorting to looking at the answer I posted :) As well as moving that line of code, you need to put it in its own `For j = 1 to n - 1` loop.

Comment: Right, I've put another loop in and everything is working fine, only difference that I made is in the final loop I made it 1 to n rather than 1 to n-1 as it wasn't displaying the last number otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your updated code which now includes the swapping of array elements, you are building the string which shows the sorted array too soon: it will show the workings rather than the final result.

All you need to do is build the string once the array is in order:

```
Private Sub btnSort_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSort.Click

    ' Bubble sort the array...
    For i = 1 To n - 1 ' When i is between 1 and the array size - 1 (8-1):
        For j = 1 To n - 1 ' Second loop - when j is between 1 and the array size - 1 (8-1):
            If Bubble(j) > Bubble(j + 1) Then ' if bubble value j is greater than value j - 1:
                temp = Bubble(j)
                Bubble(j) = Bubble(j + 1)
                Bubble(j + 1) = temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    'lblSort.Text = String.Join(vbNewLine, Bubble.Skip(1)) ' an easy one-liner

    ' Create a string to show the sorted array...
    SortedList = "" ' clear it out in case it was used previously
    For i = 1 To n
        SortedList = SortedList & Bubble(i).ToString()
        If i < n Then ' only add a newline if it isn't the last element
            SortedList = SortedList & vbNewLine
        End If
    Next

    lblSort.Text = SortedList

End Sub
```

I put the `.ToString()` in there in anticipation of you explicitly converting the input strings into numbers; strictly speaking, the `&` operator will convert its arguments into strings but I prefer to make it obvious in the code.

---

As your code is, there is an implicit conversion from the input (a string of digits) into an integer (the type of the array elements). While this seems convenient, it can be a problem if VB guesses the wrong conversion for you. There is a way to tell it to let you know if the types of variables don't match: put [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) as the very first line and it will even give you suggestions on what needs to be done to put it right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prompt the user for the input, then you will first need to either get a numeric value using a control like a NumericUpDown or you will need to convert the String value to an Integer value using [Integer.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, keep in mind that arrays in VB.Net have a 0 based index, so they start at 0, not at 1.

In terms of the Bubble Sort algorithm, you'll need a nested loop like you have with *i* and *j*, only your inner-nested loop (*j*) needs to iterate from the beginning of the array to the second to last item (0 to n-2). Inside of the nested loops, you would compare if the currently iterated value is greater than (or less than depending on which value you want to swap) than the next value. If so, then you'd just reassign the values at the currently iterated index.

Here is a console application example that I whipped up, it does not prompt the user for random values, rather it simply gets a collection of random values and then performs the Bubble Sort:

```
Private Function BubbleSort(ByVal values() As Integer) As Integer()
    'Declare placeholder variables to use in the iterations
    Dim temp As Integer

    For outterIndex As Integer = 0 To values.Length - 1
        For innerIndex As Integer = 0 To values.Length - 2
            If values(innerIndex) > values(innerIndex + 1) Then
                temp = values(innerIndex + 1)
                values(innerIndex + 1) = values(innerIndex)
                values(innerIndex) = temp
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Return values
End Function

Private r As New Random()
Private Function RandomNumbers(ByVal range As Integer) As Integer()
    'Throw an exception if the value is less than 1
    If range < 1 Then Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The range cannot be less than 1")

    'Return a collection of random numbers
    Return Enumerable.Range(1, range).Select(Function(i) r.Next()).ToArray()
End Function
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DqU8wT)